# Can't connect a mariadb server to mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-workbench, manjaro

First time using mysql and mariadb server i am not so familiar how it works.
My problem is when i go to mysql workbench and try to connect to servers there are none.
[image]

But when i go to my konzole(in linux manjaro) and type sudo systemctl status mysql it says that maria db is active(running).
My question is how can i connect to the server ?

Comment: did you try to look in mysql workbench documentation?

Comment: Really, you can't see the `+` in a circle next to `MySQL Connections`... You haven't bothered to look under the menus? Be aware though, workbench does not support mariadb and you will have difficuly making that connection.

Comment: @Bib does DBeaver support mariadb ? or tell me what supports...

Comment: Wikipedia says yes.

Comment: @Bib okay ill try that then ty :)

Comment: Making a connection to mariadb should not be difficult for mysql workbench as on protocol level mariadb and mysql are compatible. But beyond that they are not compatible any more.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem (i.e., mysql-workbench presents me with the same screen upon initially starting it while mariadb is executing).

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue last night with MySQL Workbench's latest update flatly refusing to connect to my GoDaddy powered MariaDB (It had been complaining about being incompatible for a while).

Check the [Client list @ MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/graphical-and-enhanced-clients/) to find one suitable for your OS.

For Windows users, I can recommend [HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/) for most basic management work, fairly easy to setup and for my use works near enough the same. If like me and you are using an SSH Tunnel, ensure you also have [PuTTY](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/) installed as you'll need `plink.exe` to handle the connection in the `SSH Executable` option field.